# How do I run an executable with parameters in WiX?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I want to run an executable with command line parameters in WiX. How do I pass parameters?

I would add that I need to run a console EXE file which is contained by the [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file to be installed.

I tried to add parameters somewhere in the example, step 3 at *[How To: Run the Installed Application After Setup](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/run_program_after_install.htm)*, but I have not found out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the [ExeCommand](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm) attribute to the command line you want. For the custom action used in the article you mentioned, the ExeCommand attribute can contain command line options.

Comment: I hope I already end up with it finally. But the difficulties where connected with required quotes - I have not found description in doc, sequence of custom actions and non-clear error messages in log.... It is like in dark room - I changed symbol by symbol and see what I have obtained...

Answer (score 0):

The mostly good point in creating installers is not to use a prompt by itself. This is ugly and you need to be patient on administrator rights, trying to start third-party applications.

Instead of this you can create a deferred CA, using [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++), [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) or [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). It is a bit longer, needs to know "some" syntax and so on, but you can control whatever you want. To start with, here are some resources:

- *[Deferred custom actions with WiX](http://vadmyst.blogspot.dk/2006/05/deferred-custom-actions-with-wix.html)* (simple [how-to](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how-to#Noun))
- *[CustomAction Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm)* (at WiX home on [SourceForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge))